# Assembly: The correct term of methods or functions

Tags: assembly

I've just started with learning Assembly and I would like to know the correct term of a method or function.

Like in java:

```
Public void forExample(){
Thanks thanks = new Thanks("for the answer");
}
```

this is called a method.

but what is the correct term in ASM?

```
forExample:
rjmp thanksForTheAnswer:
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Function, procedure or subroutine are common names. You might also be referring to labels in general, hard to tell.

Comment: Are there any difference between these names? or is it just a synonym of the same thing?

Comment: The difference is fairly artificial. A method acts on an object, which just means it's a function/subroutine/procedure that takes a this-pointer. In some contexts, "function" is reserved for pure functions.

Comment: Are you studying assembly on a PC ? Windows ? Mac ? Something else ?

Comment: A subroutine or procedure doesn't return a value. A function returns a value. A method is called via an object.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `forExample` and `thanksForTheAnswer` are *labels*. A label might designate the entry point of a function/method or just a branch point within such a construct. Labels can also be used to refer to data in most assembly languages.